# Chrome Push Notifications: can't subscribe from sub-path

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, web-push, push-api

I'm trying to subscribe to the `pushManager`, and I can only achieve it while on the root (`/`) path. If I navigate to any sub path (`/mypath`), I recieve `Unable to subscribe to push. DOMException: Registration failed - no sender id provided`.

The problem is that in order to subscribe, it needs to read values from `manifest.json`, which is in the root of my `public` directory. For some reason, it's trying to find the `manifest.json` file from a directory relative to the current path. For example, for `/mypath`, it will try to fetch the file from `mydomain/mypath/manifest.json`, while it should always (I believe) try to fetch the file from `mydomain/manifest.json`.

How can I solve this problem?

Link to related ticket (on a push-notification lib for Meteor I did): https://github.com/taromero/meteor-chrome-push-notifications/issues/1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a slash before the name of the manifest file. The slash denotes that it is has to pick up the file from the root of the domain.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Comment: No prob mate. Happens with everybody :)